# statistical derivation of Pearson correlation of two variables obtained from regression model

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, covariance

I have asked a stat question on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/272511/55519) which now I believe should be here. However, I repeat it here. As a newcomer, I would appreciate it if you could excuse me for any  mistakes or repeating the same question (unanswered) as I really wanted to find it out as soon as possible!

Here is the problem:

Suppose, we have developed a multiple linear regression model as follows:

$$y=a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2+⋯+a_nx_n+e=\hat y+e$$
$$z=\frac y {\hat y}=1+\frac e {\hat y}$$
now, is it possible to show mathematically that the correlations between $z$ and $x_1, x_2, ...x_n$ would be close to $0$ if all the assumptions for the regression model are met?

Empirically the relationship (both Pearson and Spearman) is zero ($0.01$ or close), however, I want to show it mathematically.

Using delta method, we can compute that, $E(1+\frac e {\hat y})=1$ and $Var(1+\frac e {\hat y})=(\frac {σ_e} {\bar y})^2$.

We can try by finding out $COV(x_1,z)$. Because,
Pearson correlation equation for $ x,y$ is, $\rho_{xy}=\frac {COV(x,y)} {\sigma_x \sigma_y}$ and $COV(x,y)=E((x-\bar x)(y-\bar y))=E(x,y)-\bar x\bar y$.

I am not from statistical background, so there is a greater chance of misinterpretation. I know that $COV(x_1,z)$ would be zero if these variables are independent. However, they are from regression model and not independent! Any suggestions or hints?

Comment: If you are going to have the question here, you need to delete the version on math.SE.

Comment: Thanks @gung for the edit. There is no option to delete the version on math.SE, only edit,share or flag! I think the question more suits here than the math.SE.

Comment: Then please flag your question on math for moderator attention: they can delete it.  In the meantime, some clarification would help.  Ordinarily $\hat{y}$ refers to an *estimator* but here you use this notation to refer to the *expectation*.  Is this what you really mean?

Comment: I cant flag it either. I am using my yahoo account to log in. I have requested in the comment section!

Thanks for the comment @whuber. By $\hat y$ i wanted to mean best fitted (estimated?) value from the multiple regression model. $y=\hat y+e$. Would you please show me where i put it as expectation? I need to correct it. To refer 'expectation' i put $E$.

Comment: The key point is that we can write the *model* as $y=a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2+⋯+a_nx_n+\varepsilon$, with variables $x_i$, parameters $a_i$, and error terms $\varepsilon$, but the *estimate* $\hat{y}$ differs from the model in many important respects: it uses *estimated* parameters and therefore the deviations between the data and the predictions are not the same as the $\varepsilon$. Typically this is written as $y=\hat{a}_0+\hat{a}_1x_1+\hat{a}_2x_2+⋯+\hat{a}_nx_n+e$ = $\hat{y} + e$ and it is rarely the case that $e=\varepsilon$.

Comment: @whuber, thanks very much for your reply. Sorry that i didnt understand it clearly. For $e$ i wanted to mean error term (which always refere as $\epsilon$ in the text book, i just wrote it quickly!). If i used it as an estimated fashion (like you said, $\hat a_i$) can i still find the $COV(x_i,z)=0$? I have checked the error assumptions (regression model, like if they normally distributed, homoscedasticity etc) and they all are met. Empirically the correlation ($corr(x_i,z)$) are always close to zero. In such case, i think there should be mathematical way to say that too!

Comment: It's still not clear what your $z$ actually is. Perhaps you could provide a tiny dataset and a worked example to help people understand what you're looking for.

Comment: $z$ is an artificial variable created from ratio of original (dependent variable, $y$) and predicted/fitted value ($\hat y$). The assumption of regression model is the error term ($\epsilon$) should not have any relation with either fitted value ($\hat y$) or independent variables ($x_i$). What i wanted to show (mathematically) is that this new variable is also have very low correlation with $x_i$. For example:

Comment: `y=[1.1,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.9,2];`
`x=[0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9];`
`mdl=LinearModel.fit(x,y,'y~x','RobustOpts','on',...`
`'VarNames',{'x','y'});`
`z=y'./mdl.Fitted;`
`corr([x',y',z])`
  Sorry couldnt able to put the results in good format. Just sample matlab code! $y$ has $0.99$ correlation with $x$, but now $z$ has only $0.06$ with $x$.

Comment: Any hints please? Just a quick add:
Is it possible to show (mathematically) that the Pearson correlation ($corr(x_i,z)$) would be less than $0.1$ if $R^2$ (coefficient of determination, obtained from multiple regression model) is greater than $0.5$ ?

Comment: is it too simple question? anyone pls!!!